# SQL server pivoting query

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, pivot

I have the dataset

```
Ptid  Test Result Date
1     BP    Neg   1/1/2013
1     CG    Pos   1/2/2013
```

I want to format the result as

```
Ptiid  BP  Date      CG   Date
1      Neg  1/1/2013 Pos  1/2/2013
```

Is this possible in sql server pivoting?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an aggregate function with a CASE expression to get the result:

```
select ptid,
  max(case when test = 'BP' then result end) BP,
  max(case when test = 'BP' then date end) BP_Date,
  max(case when test = 'CG' then result end) CG,
  max(case when test = 'CG' then date end) CG_Date
from yt
group by ptid;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/19038/1)